# I have a UISwitch on the secondView, how do I control the switch method

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I want the switch to control the user's track record, but my switch is on the secondView. Is it necessary to send notifications or use protocol delegate?

firstView

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainMapView: MKMapView!

  func drawRoute(locationArray: [CLLocation]) {
    if locationArray.count > 1 {
        let destinationLocIndex = (locationArray.count) - 1
        let startLocIndex = (locationArray.count) - 2

        let destinationloc = locationArray[destinationLocIndex].coordinate
        let startLoc = locationArray[startLocIndex].coordinate

        let routeArray = [startLoc, destinationloc]

        let geodesicLine = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: routeArray, count: routeArray.count)
        mainMapView.add(geodesicLine, level: .aboveRoads)

    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    // show current user's location
    setLocation(nowlocation: locations.last!)

    //I want to control it from the switch on the second page
    drawRoute(locationArray: userLocation)

}
}
```

seconView

```
class SencodTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func drawRouteSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if sender.isOn == true {

    } else {

    }

}
```

I want to control the drawRoute func from the second page switch, how can I do it?

Comment: You would need to use a Protocol Delegate to 'hear' events raised by the switch. You shouldn't use notifications in this situation, this is what delegates were designed for, sending events/messages/foo back.

Comment: Can you demonstrate it with code?

Comment: instead of just solving problem at hand. You should understand it. Use delegates for it. You can read how to at https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/delegate-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have a couple of options, like `NSNotification`, delegation, or even singleton (not recommended for this scenario). My favorite method for passing information between a specific pair of View Controllers like this is by delegation. It's simple. No need to go through the system's notification center. And it's specific: only one listener and one notifier.

Create the following delegate:

```
class SencodTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func switchValueDidChange(_ viewController: SencodTableViewController, isSwitchOn: Bool);
}
```

You set up the first VC as the "listener" in `prepare(for:)` method.

```
let SegueToSecondViewID = "segueToSecondViewID"

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == SegueToSecondViewID {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SencodTableViewController {
            secondVC.delegate = self
        }
    } else {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}
```

You should also make sure to define `SegueToSecondViewID` and in the storyboard as well. Go to your storyboard, click on the segue (link node between your VCs), and update the field shown in the following image:

[Segue ID update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAdMm.png)

In your first VC, also implement the "response" method by conforming to the `SencodTableViewControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
extension MapViewController: SencodTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func switchValueDidChange(_ viewController: SencodTableViewController, isSwitchOn: Bool) {
        // Do what you want with drawRoute
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to send the switch on message:

```
class SencodTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: SencodTableViewControllerDelegate?
    ...

    @IBAction func drawRouteSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate.switchValueDidChange(self, sender.isOn)
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do I want to implement  func switchValueDidChange @Sales Account

Comment: You'd extend your first VC to implement the response. See the updated answer.

Comment: If you have found the answer to be helpful please consider upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Protocol Delegate.

Start by defining a delegate (this can have any number of functions)

```
protocol SwitchToggleDelegate{
    func didToggleSwitch(state: Bool)
}
```

In your second view (with the switch):
Reference the delegate (to call the method you want)

```
var switchDelegate: SwitchToggleDelegate? = nil
```

And call the delegate method from the action of your switch: (I've included the entire code for this)

```
class View2: UIViewController {

    var switchDelegate: SwitchToggleDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func OnSwitchToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        switchDelegate?.didToggleSwitch(state: sender.isOn)
    }
}
```

In your first view:

Subscribe to your new delegate & add the required methods:

```
class View1: UIViewController, SwitchToggleDelegate { }

func didToggleSwitch(state: Bool){
        //Do Something
        labelOne.text = "Switch is \(state)"
    }
```

You will also need to set the delegate of the first view equal to the second. Since I'm using a container view for this, I'm using prepare for segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "embedded"{
        let view2: View2 = segue.destination as! View2
        view2.switchDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Now when the switch is toggled, the delegate method `func didToggleSwitch(state: Bool)` gets called and anything subscribed to this delegate method (such as your first view) will hear this delegate callback and execute whatever code you have prepared for the delegate.

Comment: Delegates are extremely useful, this is a good video going through setting them up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY. You can use them for web calls etc, they are essential for patterns like facade.

Comment: I can ask what I should do in didUpdateLocations func

Comment: When I turn the switch back to the second page he has been closed

Comment: @Josh Have you had a go at implementing this code in a standalone project? it would help you get your head around how delegates work. In your function you can do whatever you want, that is up to you!